# Generic type for an array of objects, with custom object property names

Tags: typescript

I have a `data` property inside of an object I'm looking to type in Typescript. It looks like the following:

```
type MyThing = {
  data: {
    options: {
      myKey: string,
      myValue: string
    }[],
    key: 'myKey',
    value: 'myValue'
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to instantiate types of this structure using a generic but can't quite wrap my mind around what I should be doing. Here are the requirements:

1. `key` and `value` are the base "keys" that must be supplied, but there may be others: `description` for instance
2. `options` should always be an array of objects containing only the values of the `key`, `value`, and possibly `description` defined below

I have no problems typing this literally (like in the above example). But if I want to supply custom keys and values ("myKey" and "myValue" respectively), or if I want to specify other options like a description beyond the key and value, I cannot figure out how to do such.

The desired solution would be for me to do something like this:

```
type MyThing = {
  data: DataComposer<['key', 'value']>
  // data: DataComposer<['key', 'value', 'description', ...]>
}
```

Comment: Seems you also need a type for the mapped key (i.e. `"myKey"`). Does this meet your needs? https://tsplay.dev/mb0r2w

Comment: That's fairly close @AlexWayne, but I don't necessarily need to specify the values of `key` and `value`. Those values will end up being the properties of the `options` array of objects, but injecting their values is not necessary... and in fact, the values will not be present at this location in the code. I would simply like to say "define the string for the key, define the string for the value, and use those to form the object inside of the options array".

Comment: Well then this? https://tsplay.dev/m3yqLw Problem I'm not sure where those other options like `description` or how they should be treated. Maybe you can add an example showing those?

Comment: Do the additional keys just go in `options`? https://tsplay.dev/wXK08W

Comment: They do, yes. But every time they're included in the `options` they must also be present as a property with a string value outside of `options`. Remember, the values of the "outside properties" are the KEYS of the `options` array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a type like this:

```
type DataComposer<
    K extends string,
    V extends string,
    OtherKeys extends Record<string, string> = Record<never, string>
> = {
    data: {
        options: { [optionKey in K | V | OtherKeys[keyof OtherKeys]]: string}[],
        key: K,
        value: V,
    } & { [OtherKey in keyof OtherKeys]: OtherKeys[OtherKey] }
}
```

Here `K` is the string literal for the `key` and `V` is for the `value`. Then it accepts a third parameter for a mapping of other custom properties.

Which you use like this:

```
type MyThing = DataComposer<'myKey', 'myValue'>
/*
type MyThing = {
    data: {
        options: {
            myKey: string;
            myValue: string;
        }[];
        key: "myKey";
        value: "myValue";
    };
}
*/

type MyThingWithOther = DataComposer<'myKey', 'myValue', { foo: 'myFoo' }>
/*
type MyThingWithOther = {
    data: {
        options: {
            myKey: string;
            myValue: string;
            myFoo: string;
        }[];
        key: "myKey";
        value: "myValue";
        foo: 'myFoo';
    };
}
*/
```